# error when running test on public void method when defining driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

```
package TestCart;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class LoginEnter {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

private WebDriver driver;
private LoginPage loginPage;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

}

@Test
public void successfulLoginTest() {

loginPage.open();
    assertTrue(loginPage.atPage());
    loginPage.enterUserName("standard_user");
    loginPage.enterPassword("secret_sauce");
    loginPage.clickLogin();

}

@Test
public void wrongPasswordLoginTest() {

loginPage.open();
    assertTrue(loginPage.atPage());
    loginPage.enterUserName("standard_user");
    loginPage.enterPassword("secret_sauce");
    loginPage.clickLogin();

}

@Test
public void wrongLoginNameLoginTest() {
    driver.get("https://saucedemo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id=\"user-name\"]")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id=\\\"password\\\"]\"")).sendKeys("test");
    assertEquals("Home Page", driver.getTitle());
}
}
```

I tried to rewrite the code, change the test logs, turned to neural networks and this is what they gave me

**The code block shown is a setup method which initializes the `driver` object as `ChromeDriver` and `loginPage` object as `LoginPage` with the `driver`. Without additional context or the complete code, it is not possible to say whether there is any mistake in this setup code. However, it is important to ensure that the necessary Selenium and ChromeDriver imports are added at the top of the file and that `loginPage` has been properly defined and is accessible within the test class.**

I tried to rewrite the code and change the dependencies of the method, although the build builds normally[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZIhw.png)

Comment: So what is the issue? Are you getting any error message or any failure?

Comment: I am getting an error when running the test method setUp and i can't solve it. do you need any additional information?

Comment: "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" creates a new in-method-scope instance of "driver".  Try with:  driver = new ChromeDriver();  (I'm also assuming the duplicate properties for driver and loginPage are a typo?)

Comment: @DenisKuznecow which error? Is it compilation error or runtime error. What do you expect vs what you actually get.

Comment: Alexey R.
error output "Method SetUp requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation." in run terminal Intelligence idea

Comment: pcalkins
"I'm also assuming the duplicate properties for driver and loginPage are a typo" - Yes. I defined it in another class С: driver = new ChromeDriver();